# PHP Upload working, however not storing file in directory as coded

Tags: php, file-upload

I have used this tutorial http://www.allphptricks.com/upload-file-using-php-save-directory/ to setup a form and code in PHP to upload video files. It says it was successfully uploaded each time however when I goto check there is no video file stored

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File Using PHP and Save in Directory - AllPHPTricks.com</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<form name="form" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="my_file" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<br /><br />
<a href="http://www.allphptricks.com/upload-file-using-php-save-directory/">Tutorial Link</a> <br /><br />
For More Web Development Tutorials Visit: <a href="http://www.allphptricks.com/">AllPHPTricks.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
  <?php
    if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
    // Where the file is going to be stored
        $target_dir = "upload/";
        $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
        $path = pathinfo($file);
        $filename = $path['filename'];
        $ext = $path['extension'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
        $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
     echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
     }else{
     move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
     echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Like I said, it reports the file was uploaded successfully however nothing is being actually stored and uploaded.

Comment: have you looked what the output of these variables is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using the absolute path rather than the relative path works better - it may be different on a *nix system but certainly on Windows that is true.

```
<?php
    $fieldname='my_file';
    if( isset( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] ) ){

        $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/';
        $file = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['tmp_name'];

        $filename = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
        $targetpath = $target_dir . $filename;

        if( !file_exists( $target_dir ) ){
            exit('Error: Target directory does not exist');
        }
        clearstatcache();

        if( file_exists( $targetpath ) ) {
            echo 'Sorry, file already exists.';
        }else{
            $results = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetpath );
            echo $results ? 'Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.' : 'Error-Failed to store file';
        }
        clearstatcache();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code as you suggested, and I got back a **Error-Failed to store file** I am using a centos 6 OS.

Comment: the `$target_dir` above - does it exist at the location specified?

Comment: Actually, what I noticed was the setup for my form and what you had was different. I  changed it to this`$file = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['my_file'];
        $tmp = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['tmp_name'];`  now I am getting a **Sorry, file already exists** error but when I check nothing is still uploaded or stored.

Comment: what was different? the code i posted only references the form field `my_file`

Comment: are you checking the location specified in this code or where you originally expected files to be?

Comment: in your example you had 'name' I just changed it to my_file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147660/discussion-between-ramraider-and-crazycoder).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file is probably uploaded but you don't check if it is stored. `move_uploaded_file` returns true on success and false on failure, http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php, so you need to check if it returns any error.

The problem is probably related to write access to the folder you try to store the file in